# Grabar un .csv en tabla MySQL con pandas

Tags: mysql, python, pandas, sql

Tengo el siguiente código python:

```
import pandas as pd

ruta = 'C:\\Users\\dorbezo\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\datasur\\data.csv'
e = pd.read_csv(ruta,sep=',');
```

El cual me arroja una tabla de 04 columnas.

**Deseo que estas se inserten a una tabla ya existente o desde el mismo código crear una.**

Credenciales:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.99/digemid?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"

properties = {
    "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "user": "dorbezo",
    "password": "Dorbezo123"
}

table="registros_sanitarios_peru"
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar `e.to_sql()`:

```
e.to_sql(con=con, name='registros_sanitarios_peru', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

Para crear la conexión usas `con = MySQLdb.connect(...parametros de conexión...)`, me imagino que eso ya lo tienes resuelto